# Bottlepy: Save all requests/responses in a data warehouse

Tags: nginx, bottle

I'm using bottlepy over nginx.

I'm receiving/sending a JSON in all my requests/responses.

All is working, but I don't have a historic of all requests/responses.
What is the best way to save all this information?

-> is it possible to configure bottlepy to save automátically all requests/responses? Or need I to do for each service?

-> is the best way doing in nginx?

-> what is the best database system for this situation? mongodb? cassandra? ...?

Thanks